# My heart beat really goes up during jogging, but I don't feel it

Tags: heart-rate, breathing, jogging, hiit, high-intensity

I had a very inactive lifestyle and have never been involved in any activity that keeps me in an active zone. But in recent years, I have been following a routine where I start to follow a strict diet, go to the gym, and do cardio (jogging) sessions for 3-4 months every year to maintain my weight. So I am not very experienced at workout/jogging.

This is the 5th time I am doing this, and it takes me 3 to 4 weeks to get back on track where I left off last time.

Previously, I have been doing interval training for jogging (two weeks ago I was at 60/30 seconds run/walk interval for 20-25 mins). I used to stop when it became very difficult to maintain my breath and my heart was pumping.

I changed my routine two weeks ago such that, every other day, I go straight for jogging after weight training and do a continuous slow jog (10-11 min/mile). This way I maintain my breath and when I stop I don't feel like I have done a long jog. I am quite happy with this routine and the weight loss results are also good. The problem is that my heart rate really goes up (170-180) during this jogging session but I don't even feel it going up and don't have any breathing problems. I can have a conversation while jogging. I thought there was a problem with my watch so I changed it but got a similar result on a different tracker. I am worried about keeping the heart rate at this pace for 15 minutes that I might create problems later on.
Please let me know your comments and thoughts on whether it is an okay condition or if should I change my routine.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I don't feel my increased heart rate when running either, not unless I push extremely hard.  Generally I just feel that my breathing is harder.

It's not possible to know if 180bpm is worryingly high for you.  You should look in to heart rate zones and determine if that is zone 4 or zone 5 or what.  It's possible whatever interface goes with your watch already does this.  If not just search the web for "heart rate zone calculator" and you'll get a ton of links most of which are probably using the exact same theories and formulas.

If you can run in zone 5 and still hold a conversation that seems unusual but could easily be fine.  If you are worried you could ask a doctor or even a sports physio or running coach for advice.  Next time you get a checkup you could mention your concerns to the doctor and perhaps get an ECG or some other test to verify your heart is fine.